# Javascript How to find the index of an object, of an array of dictionaries, by a given key and value

Tags: javascript

I have an array of dictionaries, where each object has the same keys but different values, like:

```
var arrayOfDicts = {};

Object 0: 'key1' : 'valueA'
          'key2' : 'valueB'
          'key3' : 'valueC'

Object 1: 'key1' : 'valueD'
          'key2' : 'valueE'
          'key3' : 'valueF'
```

How can I get the object index for a given key and value without doing a for loop? For example, the object index where 'key2' = 'valueE' will return 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are not building a function that accepts a query expression, `Array.findIndex` should be sufficient.

```js
const arr = [{
    'key1': 'valueA',
    'key2': 'valueB',
    'key3': 'valueC'
  },
  {
    'key1': 'valueD',
    'key2': 'valueE',
    'key3': 'valueF'
  }
]

const idx = arr.findIndex(({ key2 }) => key2 === 'valueE');

console.log(idx)
```